# Invite new user in google play developer console with other domain account

Tags: google-developers-console

I have a google developer account.I want to add new user to add reviews and order management on my app, is it possible to add new user in google developer account with other email. Like new user which I am going to add has email id is `a@abc.com` not `@google.com` is it possible? If not then what is the solution?

Comment: only google users can be added, as they have to login into google account

Comment: No solution yet, Only google user can be added into developer console

Answer (score 5):

You can create a Google account with your custom email address, like `a@abc.com`:

1. Press the invitation link.
2. Press Create Account.
3. On the Create your Google Account screen press "Use my current email address instead".
4. Create the account and you're good to go.

[image: Create Google account with custom email address.]

Answer (score 0):

You can only add the users who have a  Google account, Google group  or G Suite account to Google play developer console.